# Reusing wicket component in a form

Tags: wicket

I have built a wicket component that contains input/labels and methods to change presentation (required, enabled, etc.).  The components render fine, but what happens is when the form submits I see only 1 form parameter 'input', and it's the last InputRow component.

InputRow.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <label wicket:id="label">abc: <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <span class="input">
            <input wicket:id="input" type="text" id="name"></input>
        </span>
        <span wicket:id="input_feedback"></span>            
    </wicket:panel>

</body>
</html>
```

InputRow.java

```
package com.wicket;

import org.apache.wicket.behavior.AttributeAppender;
import org.apache.wicket.feedback.FeedbackMessage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

public class InputRow extends Panel{

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String id;

    public InputRow(String id, String label) {
        super(id);

        this.id = id;

         Label memberIdLabel = new Label("label",label);
         memberIdLabel.setEscapeModelStrings(false)
            .add(new AttributeAppender("for", new Model<String>(id),""));
         add(memberIdLabel);

        TextField<String> name = new TextField<String>("input");
        name.setType(String.class)
            .setMarkupId(id)
            .setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(name);

        add(new Label("input_feedback",""));

    }

    public InputRow disable()
    {
        get("input")
            .setEnabled(false)
            .add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("disabled"),""));
        get("label")
            .add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("disabled"),""));
        return this;
    }

    public InputRow required()
    {
        Model model = (Model)get("label").getInnermostModel();
        StringBuffer label = new StringBuffer((String)model.getObject());
        label.append(" <span class=\"req\">*</span>");
        model.setObject(label);

        ((TextField)get("input")).setRequired(true);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeRender() {
        super.onBeforeRender();
        Label feedback = (Label)get("input_feedback");

        if (get("input").getFeedbackMessage() != null)
        {
            feedback.setDefaultModel(new Model<String>("Required"));
        }
    }


}
```

Adding to the form component

```
add(new InputRow("name","Name:").required());
```

*edit*
I didn't set up a ListView or repeater since I know what rows / fields I want to add to the form at build time.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use models in your Input-Fields? If you use models, are they updated onSubmit?

Comment: no other reason than they weren't there when applying an example.  i'll apply the suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: Nicktar, that did the trick.  if you answer i can upvote.  tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your InputFields are missing their models. This way, wicket doesn't know where to store the formdata. If you add models to the fields they will be populated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There's not just one form parameter submitted. The submits are of the named like `name:input`, `name2:input`, ...

But as Nicktar suggests in the comment you should use a model to bind the value of the form component to your entity object. You have to accept an `IModel` in the constructor and use it in the constructor of `TextField`.

A better approach to what you are trying to do is to write a `Behavior` which adds decorating markup for your FormComponent. That way it works for more than just simple text input fields and you can fully customize the instances of your `FormComponents`.

It could look like this:

```
public class FormComponentBehavior extends Behavior {

    @Override
    public void bind(Component component) {
        if (!(component instanceof FormComponent)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeRender(Component component) {
        FormComponent<?> fc = (FormComponent<?>) component;
        Response r = component.getResponse();
        r.write("<label" + (fc.isRequired() ? " class='required'" : "") + ">");
        r.write(fc.getLabel().getObject());
        r.write("</label>");
        r.write("<span class='input'>");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterRender(Component component) {
        component.getResponse().write("</span>");
        // if feedback errors write them to markup...
    }
}
```

Then you have to add this behavior to your FormComponent instances.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with your form is that your input text fields have all the same id. Try using attribute 'name' instead of 'id'